# Why are custom HTML tags not firing in Google Tag Manager implemented via react-gtm-module

Tags: reactjs, google-tag-manager, react-gtm-module

I've implemented Google Tag Manager via the [react-gtm-module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-gtm-module). I've added Google Analytics and the Google Conversion Linker tags, which do fire on all page views / history change triggers.

My issue is custom HTML tags are not firing. I am using the same triggers as Google Analytics and Google Conversion Link -- both are using page view and history change triggers.

Does anyone know why custom HTML tags would not fire in a react app?

I've tried deleting the tags and re-adding them. I've tried publishing the changes in GTM instead of just previewing them. I've also tried setting the trigger as custom dataLayer events just to see if they fire and they do not.

Comment: Can you provide the screenshot on how you check not fired? Or anything might help it more clear about the detail

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue. Initially there were ad-blockers in place which prevented the script injection. There may be some policies which are prohibiting to inject scripts in your project too..

Also double check that you are on the correct container and the version is live.